# Check if Java application ran before

Tags: java, installation, launch

Pretty much like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608210/how-to-check-the-first-time-user-of-my-app-in-android), i'd like to check if my Java application was launched before.

Are there any standard ways in Java to do this or should i just create a file on the first launch, somewhere to indicate the application was launched before?

Comment: Do you want to check if it had ever launched before, or whether it is currently running? If you just want to check if it had run before, I would check for whatever it did the first time what you don't want to do a second time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the answer is pretty much the same on Java SE:

Check for a flag using [the `Preferences` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) ([overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html)), if doesn't exist, it's the first start.

After a successful start set that flag.

Answer (score 3):

A desktop app. can be launched using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and can access the [`PersistenceService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/PersistenceService.html).  Here is a [demo. of the persistence service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).

Use it much the same way as described in @Joachim's answer.

---

The same API also provides the [`ExtensionInstallerService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/ExtensionInstallerService.html).  The service is specifically designed to 'run first time'.  Here is a [demo. of the installer service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).

---

OTOH if you mean 'single instance', as mentioned by Peter, look to the (drum roll please..) [`SingleInstanceService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/SingleInstanceService.html) ..and the [demo. of the single instance service](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#sis).

Comment: This Java Web Start looks interesting, i'll have to look into that when i decide to make my app a bit more 'serious'. Thanks for the infos !