# App first run callback

Tags: android, callback

I need to invoke a non-database-related method **only once** when the app is run after being installed.

Are there are any callbacks I could use? I know there's SQLiteDatabase [`onUpgrade()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) method and my second alternative is to use a `Preferences` variable instead.

Comment: There is no callback method for an app's first run. If your desired action is to do with your database after an app update, then your first option will do. Otherwise, setting a flag in SharedPreferences can accomplish this behavior, and will work without having to upgrade the database.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks - my desired action isn't database related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like setting the `Preference` is your best bet.

Looks like they suggested the same in these duplicate/related questions:

[how to check the first time user of my App in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608210/how-to-check-the-first-time-user-of-my-app-in-android)

[How to know if an app runs for the first time on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269602/how-to-know-if-an-app-runs-for-the-first-time-on-device)

[Android Apllication first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217578/android-apllication-first-run)

Hope this helps.